# How can i hide the upload list in EAjaxUpload widget

Tags: file-upload, yii, yii-extensions

I'm using EAjaxUpload extension to upload multiple files but I also want to use it to upload single ones.

How can I hide the upload list in this case?

Is there any way to configure that in the widget options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under config array, you can implement these function:

```
'onSubmit' => "js:function(){
                    $('#uploadFile .qq-upload-list').html(''); // This will empty list
 }",
 'onComplete' => "js:function(id, fileName, responseJSON){

 }",
 'onProgress' => "js:function(id, fileName, loaded, total){
                }",
 'onCancel' => "js:function(){
 }"
```

Comment: I have tried it in all events and it works partially.When I put it in onSubmit, it doesn't work. If i put it in "onComplete" it works but you can see the upload. If I put it onProgress, it works but it seems the onComplete event doesnt throw, and i have some code there.

Comment: if you don't want to see result after upload complete, put code to onComplete.

Comment: Yes, that's what i did, but you can see the files while they're uploading and they hide when onComplete is thrown.
Anyway it could be a good option.

Comment: @ThanhKhánh How do I disable the `cancel`? Since I am uploading an image with small sizes, chances are the users want to cancel but it's already uploaded and would cause me heartattack from their specifications.